# SQL: Calculating Number of Days Between Dates of One Column In Different Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

With my data I have individuals taking an assessment multiple times at different dates. It looks something like this:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ Person ║ ID Number ║ Date      ║ Score ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 7/11/2013 ║ 18    ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 8/23/2013 ║ 16    ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 9/30/2013 ║ 16    ║
║ Kate   ║ 887       ║ 2/28/2013 ║ 21    ║
║ Kate   ║ 887       ║ 3/16/2013 ║ 19    ║
║ Bill   ║ 990       ║ 4/18/2013 ║ 15    ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 2/12/2013 ║ 23    ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 4/25/2013 ║ 20    ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 6/20/2013 ║ 19    ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 7/15/2013 ║ 19    ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

I'd like it to have another column at the end that calculates the number of days since the first assessment for that person. I'd also settle for the number of days since the previous assessment for that person if that's easier.

Ideally it would look like this:

```
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦══════════════════╗
║ Person ║ ID Number ║ Date      ║ Score ║ Days Since First ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 7/11/2013 ║ 18    ║ 0                ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 8/23/2013 ║ 16    ║ 43               ║
║ John   ║ 134       ║ 9/30/2013 ║ 16    ║ 81               ║
║ Kate   ║ 887       ║ 2/28/2013 ║ 21    ║ 0                ║
║ Kate   ║ 887       ║ 3/16/2013 ║ 19    ║ 16               ║
║ Bill   ║ 990       ║ 4/18/2013 ║ 15    ║ 0                ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 2/12/2013 ║ 23    ║ 0                ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 4/25/2013 ║ 20    ║ 72               ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 6/20/2013 ║ 19    ║ 128              ║
║ Ken    ║ 265       ║ 7/15/2013 ║ 19    ║ 153              ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what tool do you use to format the tables in your question?

Comment: I used: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: It was my first time trying to insert a table instead of a picture of one. Should I have done it differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select  *
,       datediff(day, min(Date) over (partition by [ID Number]), Date)
from    YourTable
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b58cd/2/0)

Comment: I am not sure this is quite right, they want the difference between the current row date and the previous date. This is giving a running total difference.

Comment: @bluefeet: From the question: "number of days since the first assessment for that person"

Comment: Maybe, I was looking at the desired result which this doesn't produce.  The OP might need to clarify.

Comment: according to the question the desired result is number of days since the first and it also said would be okay with number of days since last which was used for the example.

Comment: I realize I messed up the desired result. Sorry about that everyone. This worked just how I wanted it to. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the desired result table.

Answer (score 4):

I like Andomar's answer, but if you wanted to find both days between and total days since first you could do this:

```
SELECT a.*
        ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,b.Date,a.Date),0)'Since Previous'
        ,datediff(day, min(a.Date) over (partition by a.[ID Number]), a.Date)'Since First'
FROM (select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID Number] ORDER BY DATE)RowRank
      from    YourTable
      )a
LEFT JOIN (select  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID Number] ORDER BY DATE)RowRank
      from    YourTable
      )b
ON a.[ID Number] = b.[ID Number]
 AND a.RowRank = b.RowRank + 1
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b58cd/12/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use option with [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

1.difference between the current row date and the previous date

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(o.[Date], t1.[Date]), t1.[Date]) AS [Days Since First]
FROM YourTable t1 OUTER APPLY (
                               SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
                               FROM YourTable t2
                               WHERE t1.[ID Number] = t2.[ID Number]
                                 AND t1.[Date] > t2.[Date]
                               ORDER BY t2.[Date] DESC
                               ) o
```

See example on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b58cd/6)

2.number of days since the first assessment

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(o.[Date], t1.[Date]), t1.[Date]) AS [Days Since First]
FROM YourTable t1 OUTER APPLY (
                               SELECT MIN(t2.[Date]) AS [Date]
                               FROM YourTable t2
                               WHERE t1.[ID Number] = t2.[ID Number]                                   
                               ) o
```

See example on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b58cd/15)